# FTP upload latest files though a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

Here is the script I tried. Could someone help in fixing the bug in the script.?

FTPCommands.txt

```
open $hostname
user $username 
$password
latest_file=$(ls  File_Name* | tail -1)
binary
dir=F:/home/user/myFolder
cd $dir
put $latest_file
quit
```

Running the script as FTPTest.bat

```
ftp -i -s FTPCommands.txt > FTPLog.txt
```

While I'm calling directory in script , 550 error code is seen in the logs.

Comment: What "script" is that? How do you run it? Show us the log!

Comment: open $hostname
connected......
user $username $password
220 authenticating

dir=F:/home/user/nyfolders
latest_file=$(ls  *File_Name* | tail -1)
Invalid command

binary

cd $dir
550 Invalid sytempath

put $latest_file
Invalid command

quit

Comment: Edit the question and add the error there - with proper formatting

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing FTP commands with shell ones in your file. The forth line for example, sets a value (in bash syntax) based on the output of piped commands, one of which is `tail` - none of this is possible in the FTP protocol. Plus, judging by the .bat extension, and the path in the `dir` variable, you're running this in Windows.

Prepare the variable outside the FTP command list file (in the bat file), and have it substituted. And don't forget FTP is not a shell session, you can't issue any typical *nix commands in it.